# Current location query on click event

Tags: iphone, annotations

I am Showing Australia continent when my Map application launch. I have one button on which I want to set coding for current location and zoom in to that location after pressing butoon. I am getting current latitude & longitude and able to pass in Web-service url. I did following coding

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad 
  { 

//to set the australia region
CLLocationCoordinate2D AusLoc = {-19.048230,133.685730};
MKCoordinateSpan AusSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(45, 45);
MKCoordinateRegion AusRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(AusLoc, AusSpan);

mapView.region = AusRegion;




    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; }
```

and

```
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
  {

if((fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude) > 0.001) || (fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude) > 0.001)) {
    NSLog(@"Got location %f,%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        [currentLocation release];
    }
    currentLocation = newLocation;
    [currentLocation retain];
}
NSString *lati=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longi=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

}
```

on Search button(web service calling)

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://.....url...../hespdirectory/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=%f&lng=%f&radius=%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude,radius];
```

Updated with coding:

```
    - (IBAction) showAddress {

    if (locationManager.location == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"user location not found yet or service disabled/denied");
}
else
{



    // Change map region using span (degrees)...
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake
    (locationManager.location.coordinate, span);
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

   }
```

When I set mapView.showUserLocation = YES; it shows current location when map application launch that is before tapping button. I am confused with previous answer. So What code should I put under button click event to show current location and also suggest If there is any change to pass current Lati and longi in web service url after giving coding for click event. Thanks in advance

Edited:-

```
   - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id   <MKAnnotation>) annotation
   {
MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]   initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@""];
annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
//annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
annView.canShowCallout = YES;
annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
annView.enabled = YES;
annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flagg.png"];

UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton addTarget:self
                action:@selector(showDetails:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;    

NSLog(@"Created annotation at: %f %f",    ((CustomPlacemark*)annotation).coordinate.latitude, ((CustomPlacemark*)annotation).coordinate.longitude);

[annView addObserver:self
          forKeyPath:@"selected"
             options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
             context:@"GMAP_ANNOTATION_SELECTED"];

[annView autorelease];

return annView;
  }

  //return nil;


    - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context{

  NSString *action = (NSString*)context;

// We only want to zoom to location when the annotation is actaully selected. This   will trigger also for when it's deselected
if([[change valueForKey:@"new"] intValue] == 1 && [action   isEqualToString:@"GMAP_ANNOTATION_SELECTED"]) 
{
    if([((MKAnnotationView*) object).annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomPlacemark   class]])
    {
        CustomPlacemark *place = ((MKAnnotationView*) object).annotation;

        // Zoom into the location       
        [mapView setRegion:place.coordinateRegion animated:TRUE];
        NSLog(@"annotation selected: %f %f", ((MKAnnotationView*) object).annotation.coordinate.latitude, ((MKAnnotationView*) object).annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    }
    }
      }
```

In Search button(calling webservice)

```
     CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        //currentLocation = newLocation;

              float radius = [[arrayNo objectAtIndex:[pickerView   selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue];
    //NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.hettich.com.au/hespdirectory/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=-33.853468&lng=150.94042160000004&radius=5"];

   NSString *url = [NSString   stringWithFormat:@"http://www.hettich.com.au/hespdirectory/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=%f&lng=%f&radius=%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude,radius];
//NSLog(@"NSString *url");
NSLog(@"%@", url);
   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
//Initialize the delegate.
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
//Set delegate
  [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
//Start parsing the XML file.
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];
if(success)

{       resultButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
          //    NSMutableArray* annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [appDelegate.markers count]; i++)
{

    marker *aMarker = [appDelegate.markers objectAtIndex:i];
    location.latitude = [aMarker.lat floatValue];
    location.longitude =[aMarker.lng floatValue];
    AddressAnnotation *annob = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
    annob.title = aMarker.name;
    annob.subTitle = aMarker.address;
    [mapView addAnnotation:annob];
    [annob release];


    CLLocationCoordinate2D ausLoc = {location.latitude,location.longitude};         //for zoom in the showroom results region
    MKCoordinateSpan ausSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.108889, 0.169922);
    MKCoordinateRegion ausRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(ausLoc, ausSpan);
    NSLog(@"No Errors");
    mapView.region = ausRegion;



}


}
```

Comment: Do you want to center the map on the user's location only when the button is tapped or whenever the user's location changes?

Comment: When I open application I have mapView with australia continent and one UIview which cover half of screen. The UIview is contain the following buttons Show Me, Radis picker, Search. So when I tap the Show me button I want to show the Current location of user. And yes I can hide my UIview to show the whole mapView. Yes I want to center the map on the user's location only when the button is tapped.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button tapped method, you should first check if the location manager has obtained a location and then set the map's center or region to the user's location:

```
if (locationManager.location == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"user location not found yet or service disabled/denied");
}
else
{
    // Change map center (preserving current zoom level)...
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:locationManager.location.coordinate animated:YES];

    // --OR--

    // Change map region using distance (meters)...
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance
                           (locationManager.location.coordinate, 1000, 1000);
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    // --OR--

    // Change map region using span (degrees)...
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake
                           (locationManager.location.coordinate, span);
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

In the `didUpdateToLocation` method, you are setting a "currentLocation" variable but I don't see a need for it.  The `locationManager` already has a `location` property.

In any case, only considering absolute latitudes or longitudes greater than 0.001 as "valid" is incorrect because a) it excludes locations near the equator or prime meridian (even though you're only interested in Australia this logic is the wrong way to go), and b) it's better instead to check if `newLocation` itself is `nil`.

Comment: Now when I am launching my application it opens with current location region directly. I want Australia continent first then by tapping Show me button it should open current locaiton region. I have updated my coding as well as Question with your answer. Can you just check and rectify where I am lacking......

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate that problem with the code shown.  Have you implemented any map delegate methods like didUpdateUserLocation where you also update the map's region?  If so, disable that code.

Comment: I have put in -(void) viewDidload{CLLocationCoordinate2D AusLoc = {-19.048230,133.685730};
MKCoordinateSpan AusSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(45, 45);
MKCoordinateRegion AusRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(AusLoc, AusSpan);

mapView.region = AusRegion;
}    Also where my multiple annotation get place on Map there I have put region.

Comment: Can I mail you my class file coding???? So at least you know that where I am lacking...I tried with this several ways but didnt get any solution

Comment: It sounds like the problem is setting the region where you place the annotations.  Show that code.

Comment: thanks for replying..I have place more code. I hope you can understand.

Comment: In the loop that adds the markers, comment out the code at the bottom that sets the mapView.region.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much....I also made one change instead of setting Australia region in viewDieLoad method I set in ViewWillAppear{}